# ASP.NET Web API Authentication For Xamarin App

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, asp.net-identity

I've recently been learned how to implement a token based authentication with ASP.NET and I would love to get some input on how my code & structure is as well as how I can make it better.

The code I'd like to share consists of the ASP.NET web API controller, and the client Xamarin application.

One question I have been having is am I taking the proper approach with refreshing the token every time the app is launched (and the user has already entered their credentials prior?)

Web API Controller:

```
  [HttpPost("token")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GenerateToken([FromForm]LoginModel model)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
        if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
        {
            var token = _identityService.GenerateToken(user);
            string tokenText = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

            var refreshToken = _identityService.GenerateRefreshToken();
            user.RefreshToken = refreshToken;
            _context.Update(user);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            string expirationString = token.Claims.Single(x => x.Type == "exp").Value;
            DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(long.Parse(expirationString));

            return Ok(new
            {
                token = tokenText,
                refreshToken,
                expiration = dateTimeOffset
            });
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your email or password did not match any users. Please verify you have entered the right credentials.");
        return Unauthorized(ModelState);
    }

[HttpPost("RefreshToken")]
    public IActionResult RefreshToken([FromForm]string token, [FromForm]string refreshToken)
    {
        var principal = _identityService.GetPrincipalFromExpiredToken(token);
        var username = principal.Identity.Name;

        var allClaims = principal.Claims.ToList();
        var name = allClaims.First(c => c.Type.Contains("nameidentifier")).Value;
        var user = _context.Users.Single(x => x.UserName == name);

        var savedRefreshToken = user.RefreshToken; 
        if (savedRefreshToken != refreshToken)
            throw new SecurityTokenException("Invalid refresh token");
        
        var newJwtToken = _identityService.GenerateToken(user);
        var newRefreshToken = _identityService.GenerateRefreshToken();

        user.RefreshToken = newRefreshToken;
        _context.Update(user);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        string tokenText = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(newJwtToken);

        string expirationString = newJwtToken.Claims.Single(x => x.Type == "exp").Value;
        DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(long.Parse(expirationString));

        return new ObjectResult(new
        {
            token = tokenText,
            refreshToken = newRefreshToken,
            expiration = dateTimeOffset
        });
    }
```

Xamarin Client

```
private async void RefreshToken()
{
    // get the saved refresh token
    string refreshToken = CrossSettings.Current.GetValueOrDefault("RefreshToken", "_");
    string token = CrossSettings.Current.GetValueOrDefault("Token", "_");
    // the IDatabaseManager implementation simply makes the HTTP calls
    var db = TinyIoCContainer.Current.Resolve<IDatabaseManager>();
    // returns http result from HTTP call to refresh token controller action
    var response = await db.RefreshToken(token, refreshToken);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IdentityResponse>(contentString);
        var newToken = content.Token;
        var newRefreshToken = content.RefreshToken;
        db.SetToken(token);
        CrossSettings.Current.AddOrUpdateValue("RefreshToken", newRefreshToken);
        CrossSettings.Current.AddOrUpdateValue("Token", newToken);
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomeMaster());
        isLaunched = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        // the refresh token is invalid
        MainPage = new LoginPage();
        await MainPage.DisplayAlert("Authentication Error", "You have been logged out", "Ok");
    }
  }
```

When the Xamarin app is launched, it will check for an existing token first. If a token is found, the RefreshToken method is called. If not, it brings the user to the login screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fine to refresh the token on every app start.

It will also prevent potential hijacked tokens to be usefull for a longer time, when the token is refreshed everytime the user starts the app and the old token becomes invalid.